Determinism in relativity
We know that transitioning from classical mechanics to quantum mechanics, determinism breaks down. We also know that complexity and chaos theory have determinism in principle but we can't predict. My question is what happens in the relativistic mechanics? Does determinism work in special relativity and general relativity?
How does strong censorship conjecture prove/imply the global determinism of spacetime and the inaccessibility of singularities, thereby preserving the predictive power of the theory?

It is subtle.
Special relativity is deterministic. If you give initial conditions to a well-posed problem, you get a solution. Relativity doesn't get in your way concerning that.
General relativity is more subtle. If you give initial data for spacetime (so you tell the initial geometry), you can evolve this geometry and predict how the rest of spacetime looks like, assuming the initial geometry is allowed (this is similar to how the divergence of electric and magnetic fields has to be given in terms of the charge density or vanish: you can't choose it arbitrarily).
Now, suppose you are given a spacetime and you want to evolve things in there. Can you do it? Not always. Some spacetimes might have naked singularities, which allow things to enter or exit the spacetime without any rules on how they do it, or may have a more complicated causal structure. It is very nuanced.
It is believed that all physical spacetimes are deterministic in a very specific sense (they are globally hyperbolic). This is known as the strong censorship conjecture.

please explain the connection between globally hyperbolic and determinism

@physics Initial value problems for differential equations are only well-posed in globally hyperbolic Spacetimes

so the Strong Censorship Conjecture is a profound hypothesis in general relativity that asserts the global determinism of spacetime and the inaccessibility of singularities, thereby preserving the predictive power of the theory ?

@physics Yes, that's the essential idea

Any reference for causal structure for the above

@physics Wald's General Relativity chapter 8, or Hawking & Ellis' The Large Scale Structure of Spacetime

The relativistic theories are deterministic in nature, in this sense, they are no different than classical theories. In the relativistic theories, it is the classical concepts of simultaneity that break down.

I think it's a little worse than that. In non-relativistic physics we could pretend that the initial conditions were knowable and then the theory could predict the future. In relativistic theories some of the initial conditions of the future are located in space-like separated regions, i.e. they are, at least locally, unknowable, unless we know the initial conditions of the entire universe. For all practical purposes the future is therefor not predicable. So at least in a very naive sense, future physics is not deterministic. We have to pretend to have "god mode" to make it predicable.

@FlatterMann Excellent point! The relativistic theories can still be considered in the "God mode" sense to be deterministic; such pretensions will not save determinism in the quantum mechanical case; thus the quantum theories are truly indeterminate.

I agree. In quantum mechanics the outcome of a measurement is also tied to the unknown state of a local measurement system (which is acknowledged in decoherence scenarios) and, if I am not mistaken, even to the entire state of the local future light cone, so we basically don't have the full picture in either direction.
